# Different behavior of sum of numpy arrays with regards to data type when using increment operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

Consider the following sum of numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 10])
b = np.array([1.3, 1.3])
a = a+b
print a
```

This will print:

```
array([ 11.3,  11.3])
```

Now, if I use `+=`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 10])
b = np.array([1.3, 1.3])
a +=b
print a
```

The result:

```
array([11, 11])
```

What the explanation for this behavior? I'm using python 2.7.7 and numpy 1.8.2

Answer (score 3):

As a [warning in wiki](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-and-comparison-operations):

> In place operations will perform the calculation using the precision decided by the data type of the two operands, but will silently downcast the result (if necessary) so it can fit back into the array. Therefore, for mixed precision calculations, `A {op}= B` can be different than `A = A {op} B`.For example, suppose `a = ones((3,3))`. Then, `a += 3j` is different than a = a + 3j: while they both perform the same computation, `a += 3` casts the result to fit back in a, whereas `a = a + 3j` re-binds the name a to the result.

So in this case as the format of the elements of array `a` is `int`, `a +=b` will casts the result to fit back in a.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, but I would likely not figure it out by myself. This kind of _in place_ operations should be used carefully.

Comment: @Anselmo you're welcome! yeah, numpy has a strange behavior with types!

Answer (score 0):

```
a += b # a is an integer array, b is a float array, a stays a float integer array
```

This is because the first array is an integer array so the values are casted to match the left hand side. Basically in the code above, the array retains its integer disposition through an implicit cast because that is what it is at the moment. Below, the two are simply added and reassigned which allows for such a change.

```
a = a + b # a is an integer array, b is a float array, a is reassigned to result
```